v-select drop down error [object Object] selected the value
i am a begineer of vuejs. i want to add the record using api.if i select the status as true 1 need to be selected other wise 2 will be selected and add into the database table. but i checked through the console after selected the true option click submit button.display as v-select drop down error [object Object] selected the value why. what i tried so far i attached below of the code snippt please look at the code and give me the solution and rewrite it.
Form
 <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label>Status</label>
                          <v-select  v-model="selectedStatus"
                          label="Select"
                          :items="['True', 'False']"
                          @change="updateStatus"
                        ></v-select>
                      </div>

here is the vue js validation js
data() {
    return {
      selectedStatus: '',
      openmodel: "Open",
      updatedialog: false,
      selectedRow: {},
      form: {
        status: null,
      },
      result: [],
      baseUrl:
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee",
    };
  },
  created() { 
        this.AllEmployees();
    },
  methods: {
    
    updateStatus(value) {
      this.form.status = value === 'True' ? 1 : 2;
    },

    async addCategory() 
    {
     await EmployeeApi.addReview(this.form);
    },

screen shot error
enter image description here
